# Agrupar por intervalo de idade

Tags: mysql

Gostaria de tabelar os clientes cadastrados numa base de dados `mysql` pelo intervalo de idades.

Tenho um campo `nascimento` tipo `date`.

Com a consulta abaixo consigo agrupar por nascimento.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS qtd, YEAR(FROM_DAYS(TO_DAYS(NOW())-
TO_DAYS(nascimento))) AS idade FROM cliente GROUP BY nascimento ASC ORDER BY qtd DESC
```

Porém me retorna a quantidade apenas para a idade exata do `group by`, gostaria de uma contagem de um intervalo (exemplo abaixo):

```
30 - 20~25 anos
20 - 25~30 anos
10 - 30~35 anos
```

Como adequar a consulta acima para que ela apresente esse tipo de resposta?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para fazer isso você precisa criar um "case" para agrupar os resultados de acordo com o intervalo de idade que você quer. Aqui tem um exemplo:

```
select 
case 
when T2.idade between 0 and 19 then 'Ate 19' 
when T2.idade between 20 and 25 then 'De 20 a 25' 
when T2.idade between 26 and 30 then 'De 26 a 30' 
when T2.idade between 31 and 35 then 'De 31 a 35' 
when T2.idade between 36 and 120 then 'De 36 a 120' 
end as faixas, sum(T2.total) as total
from ( SELECT YEAR(now()) - YEAR(nascimento) - ( DAYOFYEAR(now()) < DAYOFYEAR(nascimento)) as idade, count(*) as total 
from cliente  
group by idade) T2 
group by faixas
```

Comment: Funcionou lindamente, obrigado!